# Webpack project is not running after npm start on the server in development mode

Tags: angularjs, node.js, deployment, server, webpack

Hi i am trying to deploy my code(Angular.js +webpack_node.js) to the development server from local environment and have written following code. BUt it seems to not work and npm run deploy is giving me lot of warning and on reloading the dns the page is empty.

### Package.JSON

```
{
  "name": "opgadminsuite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "New adminsuite with client side independence",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "local": "webpack-dev-server --content-base app",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack.development.config.js",
    "clean": "rm app/bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-clipboard": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-ui-router-styles": "0.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "bootstrap-webpack": "0.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

### Webpack.development.config.js

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  context:path.resolve( __dirname + '/app'),
   entry:   "./index.js",
  output:{
    path:__dirname + "/app",
    filename:"bundle.js",
  //   publicPath: "http://localhost:9090/build/"
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css', { allChunks: true })
  ],
  module:{
    loaders:[
        {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: '/node_modules/',
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ["es2015"],  
        }

      },
             {test: /bootstrap\/js\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
            {test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'},
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
            {test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
    ]
  },
 devServer:{
    inline:true,
    port:8080
  },
   debug: true
}
```

### Server.js

```
 var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

var host = 'localhost';
// Serve application file depending on environment
app.get('/index.js', function(req, res) {
    if (process.env.PRODUCTION) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.js');
    } else {
        res.redirect('//' + host + ':9090/app/index.js');
    }
});


var appVersions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    var vee = '/' + i + '.index.js'
    appVersions.push(vee)
}
appVersions.forEach(function(name) {
    app.get(name, function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/' + name);
    });
});

// Serve aggregate stylesheet depending on environment
app.get('/style.css', function(req, res) {
    if (process.env.PRODUCTION) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/style.css');
    } else {
        res.redirect('//' + host + ':9090/app/style.css');
    }
});

// Serve index page
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');
});


if (!process.env.DEVELOPMENT) {
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
    var config = require('./webpack.development.config');

    new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
        publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
        hot: true,
        noInfo: true,
        historyApiFallback: true
    }).listen(8080, host, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
} else {
    console.log("DEVELOPMENT mode On")
}



var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var server = app.listen(port, function() {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Essential Angular listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Also here host variable is comming empty. Can anyone tell me what am i missing here. Might be silly or might be  a duplicat e, any help is appreciated.

I have researched and got to this state, so pls dont downvote and kindly help.
Pls suggest , thanks!

Comment: what is your production webpack?

Comment: correction its a development mode.. we are moving it from local to development

Comment: A comment for future : I had the same problem I just run `clean install` before to run the project ;)